# HLSL problem with divide by homogeneous component

Tags: xna, hlsl

When I try to divide my position.z by my position.w in HLSL I get as result always 1.0f or higher. Is this a common problem for some reason? When I divide my position.x or y by the w this works fine. But the divide for the z gives a wrong result. I use the view matrix for my camera and the projection matrix as i use it in the game because I want to create a depthmap from the cameraposition. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong? Do I need another view matrix?

Comment: I found out my lookat in my view layed before the draw point of the model which had influence on my z value. Now i've put my lookat further away and get a good result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my lookat in my view layed before the draw point of the model which had influence on my z value. Now i've put my lookat further away and get a good result.